# Eliminate html tags from values

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to eliminate HTML tags from a value displayed in an ssrs report.

My solution came to:
=(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]*>")).Replace((new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("< STYLE >. *< /STYLE >")).Replace(Fields!activitypointer1_description.Value,""),"")

The problem is that the second expression ("< STYLE >. *< /STYLE >" without the spaces) which should be executed first doesn't do anything. The result contains the styles from the html without the  tags attached.

I'm out of ideas.

C

Comment: What is the second Regex for?

Comment: Post a most clear example as to what you are looking for.

Comment: The second expression is not executing first. What made you think it executes first?

Comment: What made me think that?
1st thing that pops in mind is the language.
I mean, if I take the code and execute it in a C# program, it does what it should.
What makes you think it executes second?

Comment: oops, my bad. You're right, the STYLE regex does execute before the HTML one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add RegexOptions.Singleline, because by default Regular expressions will stop on newline characters. Here's an example of a console program you can run to verify it:

```
string decription = @"<b>this is some 
text</b><style>and 
this is style</style>";
        Console.WriteLine(
            (new Regex( "<[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline ))
            .Replace(
                (new Regex( "<STYLE>.*</STYLE>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline ))
                    .Replace( decription
                    , "" )
            , "" )
         );
```

Comment: the SingleLine Option was the thingy
10x